# How can I hide my bootstrap modal form after successfully submitting of form data in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I have applied server side validations on my rails form .. using ajax and bootstrap now I want to hide my modal after successfully submitting my form .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guest that you're using ajax to submit the form in your Bootstrap modal.

After that, controller action will render the `js` response (for example: `create.js.erb`)

Edit: In order to set conditional statements

In controller action

```
@object = YourModel.new(params[:object])
unless @object.save
  @errors = @object.errors.full_messages
end
```

In `create.js.erb`

```
<% if @errors %>
  /* DO form invalid actions, like show error messages */
<% else %>
  $('#yourModalID').modal('hide');
<% end %>
```

Comment: This will work even when the form gets successfully submitted or not ...so I think o have to add some conditions ..and I don't know about that

Comment: how about setting `@error` in action. Edit my answer

Comment: Setting...? What's that? Please let me know

Comment: Can you please provide me a sample code I am a really beginner

Comment: Np, I hope u can make it works also, and, don't forget to mark my answer as solution :)

Answer (score 0):

In controller action

```rb
def create
  @object = YourModel.create(params)
end
```

create file `create.js.erb`

```rb
<% if @object.valid? %>
  $('#yourModalID').modal('hide');
  /* DO actions, like append object to list */
<% else %>
  /* DO form invalid actions, like show error messages */
<% end %>
```